# Solidity how to get random number with ratio

Tags: solidity

I want to create my own NFT according to ERC1155 standard.

My hero has 6 parts, each part has 4 types as shown in the picture.

Now I want to create a function that takes a random number with the ratio shown in the image.

Here is simple function return random number. With `_mod = 10^n` it will return number of length n-1.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract RandomNumbers{
    function random(uint _mod) public view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,block.difficulty,  
        msg.sender))) % _mod;
    }
}
```

[image]

I've been struggling with this for a whole day.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know. You shouldn't use `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,block.difficulty,msg.sender))` to generate a random number because that actually creates a pseudo-random guessable number. Take a look at [Chainlink VRF](https://chain.link/chainlink-vrf).

For the ratio you could try to check out this [Data structure](https://medium.com/kleros/an-efficient-data-structure-for-blockchain-sortition-15d202af3247) ([GitHub](https://github.com/kleros/kleros/blob/master/contracts/data-structures/SortitionSumTreeFactory.sol)): you manually set values for the leaves and then when you have your random number you can call the `draw` function to set the different stats.